# jQuery nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am still new to JavaScript and jQuery, so I am confused as to why the following code is not working as I anticipated.  All I am trying to do is save input on a button click (`id=recordInput`) and display it with another button click (`id=displayInput`).  What I observe is that `tempInput` is stored, (the code works until that point) but assignment of displayInputs onclick attribute is not executed.  My question is, can you not nest a `$().click()` call inside of another `&().click()` call?

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#recordInput').click(function(event) {
        var tempInput = $('#testInput').val();
        &('#displayInput').click(function(event) {
            console.log(tempInput);
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

My thinking is this in pseudocode:

1. assign recordInput onclick attribute to the following function:
2. store tempInput
3. set displayInput onclick to alert the tempInput value

what is wrong with my thinking?

NOTE: I did not include any html tags but all of the ids are referenced correctly

Comment: Did you mean $('#displayInput') ?

Comment: Replace `&` with `$` in the nested one.

Comment: Like stated above you used a `&` instead of a `$`. Please check your console before posting.

Comment: In addition to the typo, your design is suspicious. It's almost always wrong to declare one event handler inside another. Every time you click on `recordInput`, it's going to add an additional click handler to `displayInput`, so the second function will run multiple times when you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you have put `&` instead of `$` here

```
$('#displayInput').click(function(event) {
```

Fixing this may work, but you shouldn't set event handlers this way. Because every time your first handler function is called it will set an event handler for the second one. You can try with your `console.log` and you will see that the number of `console.log` is increasing by every click on `#recordInput`. So you should better set it like this :

```
var tempInput;
$('#recordInput').click(function(event) {
    tempInput = $('#testInput').val();
});
$('#displayInput').click(function(event) {
    console.log(tempInput);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#recordInput').click(function(event) {
        var tempInput = $('#testInput').val();
        &('#displayInput').click(function(event) {
            console.log(tempInput);
        });
    });
});
```

to

```
$(function(){

var testInput = '';
$('#recordInput').click(function(){
  testInput = $('#testInput').val();
});
$('#displayInput').click(function(){
  if(testInput !== ''){
    console.log(testInput);
  }
});

});
```

You are using `&` instead of `$`. Of course, you don't have to format the code exactly like I did.